# How to manipulate post data in cakephp before saving?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple form which has 3 fields. User has the option to leave the third field blank. In that case, a value will be created by concatenating first two fields and  be saved in the database against the third field. I have tried following from the controller:

```
if (empty($this->request->data('Program.progam_code'))) {
                $this->request->data('Program.progam_code') = 
                    $this->request->data('Program.batch_id') . "-"
                    . $this->request->data('Program.default_progam_code');  
            }
$this->Program->save($this->request->data;
```

This code gives following error:

```
Error: Can't use method return value in write context
```

How to achieve the desired outcome? Any ideas?

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting via:

```
$this->request->data['Program']['progam_code'] = "your value";
```

Comment: Awesome - you're welcome! If this was helpful, please choose it as the accepted answer. Thanks :)